# how to include other jquery file and css file in wordpress plugins

Tags: css

I have jquery file like as follows

"portfolio.css"
"jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"
"portfolio.js"

I want to include these files into my plugin...
if anyone have solution for how to include above mentioned file into wordpress plugin then tell me....

please....
thank you in advance

Comment: Where will these files be used? Front end or backend?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this snippet inside your function:

```
wp_register_style('mycss', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/whatever.css');
wp_enqueue_style('mycss');
```

Then you add this add_action after your function,  to call your the CSS in the :

```
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'your_function_name');
```

For javascript, use `wp_register_script()` and  `wp_enqueue_script()` instead.

WordPress function reference:
[wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and 
[wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: Wrong way bro... This is now deprecated, should be done using the `wp_enqueue_script` action hook.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to Your plugin-name.php file and before you do that change css and js directory

```
 function my-plugin(){

 wp_enqueue_style('my-portfolio-style',plugins_url('css/portfolio.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui',plugins_url('css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-portfolio',plugins_url('js/portfolio.js',__FILE__));

    }

    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','my-plugin');
```

> OR

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my-plugin');   //for Backend , use only one because your question is limited
```